# ios notifications to "dead" objects

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, nsnotificationcenter

I have a number of UIViews coming into view, then going out of view and being unused. However, I believe some of them are still receiving notifications even after they are gone wich is causing problems.

On the UIView "parent" container:

```
if(self._content != nil && [self._content respondsToSelector:@selector(presentMe:)]) {
    [self._content presentMe:NO];
}
```

On the UIView "child":

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] <-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x70000008
 postNotificationName:PRESENTING 
 object:self 
 userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:prepareToEnter], PRESENTING, nil]];
```

Everything works the first time around, but if I launch the same view a second time I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Doesn't that mean something is missing?

*FYI this is all in ARC - xcode 4.3.2*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are calling `addObserver` for items in your view, you need to call `removeObserver` during dealloc.  Even with ARC.