# NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName exec_badaccess

Tags: iphone, uiview, viewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I have a view controller, when it's dissming with completion, I post a notfication, and in a subview which contained in another view controller, has added as a oberserve. But, when it tries to execute post notificaiton methode, exec_bad_access happend. what's wrong? The codes are:

```
BrandListByIdViewController.m

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSNumber *bid = self.brands[indexPath.row][@"id"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SelectedBrandId" object:nil];
    }];

}

SearchNewProduct.h

@interface SearchNewProduct : UIView

@end

SearchNewProduct.m

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didSelectedBrandId::) name:@"SelectedBrandId" object:nil];
    }
}

- (void)didSelectedBrandId:(NSNotification *)notif{

    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

Even I get rid of the userInfo, still bad access. I created a similar situation in another new project, it works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't realize that you were dealing with a `UIView` and not a `UIViewController` (should have read your question better).  I think what is happening is that the View is receiving notifications even after being released.  Make sure to call `dealloc` in your `UIView` and remove itself as an observer:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Also, put an `NSLog` in that `UIView`'s `initWithFrame` method to see if it is being called more than once.

This question is very similar:

[ios notifications to "dead" objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323087/ios-notifications-to-dead-objects)

Comment: `bid` shouldn't be released because it is the member of the user-info dictionary (which retains its values and copies its keys)

Comment: I have tried put the postNotificationName method before the completion of dismiss. No matter where i put the code. This view controller will dismiss eventually. I have tried delegate, but it seems not working. the delegate method won't execute in the uiview.

Comment: Amended my answer.  I thought you were dealing with two ViewControllers.  Delegate's belong in VC's.  You could do the delegate method and let the VC that owns that View handle it, or try the amended answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the reason, but when you add your view to the notification center, your selector is wrong:

```
selector:@selector(didSelectedBrandId::)
```

There should only be one colon. The entire line should be:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didSelectedBrandId:) name:@"SelectedBrandId" object:nil];
```

Two colons indicates the method takes two arguments, but it only takes one.